# Find shortest path between points without entering a polygon

Tags: geometry

Is there a way to calculate what is the shortest path if I have two points that have a polygon between them. Touching the polygon is allowed but crossing is not.

I have several examples here:

[image]

I have highlighted the optimal paths in all 3 cases with green. The goal in each of them is get from A to B, F to G, and K to L.

Is there a theorem for this or a rule that can help me identify the shortest constrained path ?

Very grateful for any opinions

Comment: Observe that if the optimal path touches the polygon, it both enters and exits the polygon at a vertex. So, consider paths from the starting point, to some vertex, to some other vertex, to the end point. Also make sure to just try the straight line.

Comment: Some points that would bear clarification:  Is there only one polygon to be "avoided"?  Is that polygon convex?  The examples suggest as much, but it would be helpful to state explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that polygon (P) is convex.

Consider the convex hull of the union

$$(P) \cup \{A\} \cup \{B\}$$

where $(P)$ denotes the vertices of the polygon, $A$ and $B$ the endpoints of the path.

This convex hull necessarily contains points $A$ and $B$ and some vertices of $(P)$. Usual software (like Matlab's "convhull") give this convex hull with points numbered for example in the direct orientation.

Now consider the two paths joining $A$ to $B$ in this convex hull and choose the shortest one.

[image]

Here is the Matlab program that has generated the figure

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal;
> n=8;r=2*pi*rand(n,1);r=sort(r);
> s=[r;r(1)];plot(cos(s),2*sin(s),'r');% polygon's vertices
> A=[-3;0];B=[4;0.5];% endpoints
> CR=[cos(r);[A(1);B(1)]];SR=[2*sin(r);[A(2);B(2)]];
> I=convhull(CR,SR);% indexing table
> plot(CR(I),SR(I),'g')
> ```

Comment: Convex hull approach will only work when the polygon is convex. Consider the following [simple case](https://i.imgur.com/PsyEwEJ.png). At extreme cases, this problem is almost as hard as finding [the shortest path in a maze](https://i.imgur.com/LSiPXrV.png).

Comment: @Vasily Mitch Yes , it is why I have placed this condition in my first sentence. One could bypass this by taking first the convex hull of the vertices of the polygon...